# Bootstrap Menu not collapsing correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We're building a website using bootstrap and having a bit of a problem with the menu.

If you look at http://www.tempsite.co.uk/bstrp/ - The top menu appears fine and it also collapes ok when viewing on a mobile device.

However, when I try to reduce the size of my browser to see the breaking points, there a point in which the menu doesn't collapse correctly.

[image]

It's between medium and small.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Just a note.. you've got the following error `TypeError: $(...).pullOutContentPanel is not a function`

Comment: You have FOUC that doesn't dissapear after full load.

Comment: Thanks Izzy - I've corrected the error.
Milan - What do you mean by FOUC?

Comment: Try to use @media queries

Comment: Joci93 - Not used them before.  Can you give an example based on what i've done?

Comment: [media queries](http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html)

Comment: Joci93 - See: http://www.tempsite.co.uk/bstrp/

Comment: for example (add to your css):
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
.collapse ul{
 width:95%;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner-small .nav li{
 width:20%;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner-small .brand{
 display:none;
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by changing the breakpoint for the grid system or overriding the css so that the navbar will be collapsed for medium devices (tablets) using the following code:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block!important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.6px -16px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
    }
}
```